# What is liquibase default behaviour in JHipster?

Tags: jhipster, liquibase

In previous spring boot apps I have worked with, hibernate has been whats taken care of changes to the database, whether it be the data imports on startup or modifying the database if the entity's change.

So if I changed an entity the spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto setting would be what determines how the database is changed. Is liquibase what is doing this in a jhipster app? I'm mostly concerned about what liquibase does to modify the database, apposed to the versioning aspect

Answer (score 0):

The Liquibase creates 2 tables for its own purposes **DATABASECHANGELOG** and **DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK**.

**DATABASECHANGELOG** keeps records of what all changesets have been applied on the database so far.

JHipster uses Liquibase to manage the database updates, and stores its configuration in the **/src/main/resources/config/liquibase/** directory.

If you prefer (or need) to do a database update manually, here is the development workflow:

- Modify your JPA entity (add a field, a relationship, etc.)
- Create a new “change log” in your src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog directory.
- Add this **“change log”** file in your src/main/resources/config/liquibase/master.xml file, so it is **applied the next time you run your application**

If you want to skip Liquibase migrate task during startup application, you can using profile "**no-liquibase**". *Ex: spring.profiles.active=prod,no-liquibase*

More information on using Liquibase, please go to http://www.liquibase.org.

Comment: Thanks!I would want liquibase to still create/populate the jhipster tables for user etc, but do pretty much nothing else. Let updates/changes to other tables/entities be done by hibernate. How would I do that?

Comment: JHipster using [Liquibase Hibernate Extension](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-hibernate/wiki). You can update Hibernate mapped classes as needed and then, you can use the **./mvnw liquibase:diff** goal to automatically generate a changelog.

Comment: What is the out of the box process with default behaviour that happens if I Update an existing entity using Jhipster as described here https://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-entity/ So the entity is now different to what is currently in the database, does jhipster add liquibase files that will modify the database?

Comment: In short, workflow:
1. Create an entity

2. Execute mvn command:./mvnw liquibase:diff ->  schema comparisons -> auto generate changelogs file (.xml file)

3. Liquibase will modify the database during startup application base on changeLogs file